# Previous versions of file are not visible in SMB client

Tags: c++, windows, windows-10, protocols, smb

We are implementing SMB2 protocol. In order to show previous file versions client sends `SMB2 IOCTL reqeust with CtlCode of FSCTL_SRV_ENUMERATE_SNAPSHOTS`. We send a response as described in http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/5/E/95EF66AF-9026-4BB0-A41D-A4F81802D92C/%5BMS-SMB2%5D.pdf 3.3.5.15.1 Handling an Enumeration of Previous Versions Request

When I click on Properties->Previous versions of a directory it shows previous versions returned, but for files it doesn't show anything. I checked that we return the same response for both files and directories.

Why doesn't it work for files? How files and directories are different regarding to previous versions? What other requests should be supported to view previous versions of a file in windows client?

Comment: Developing a server you must be receiving all requests that client sends. Why not to log all requests and check them one by one?

Answer (score 1):

I've sniffed some localhost communication when opening directory/file properties (previous version tab). Found that the client sends CreatFile requests ([MS-SMB2], 2.2.13SMB2 CREATE Request) with SMB2_CREATE_TIMEWARP_TOKEN ([MS-SMB2], 2.2.13.2.7) in CreateContexts. Client gets the list of snapshots and then cycling timestamps doing Create request  using timestamp in SMB2_CREATE_TIMEWARP_TOKEN.
Suppose client tries to open file from different snapshots and compare changes using file modification time. Then display all different versions.

Comment: Are REPARSE_POINTS required to support previous versions?

Comment: If I send you the capture file can you tell what part is wrong ?

Comment: @Ashot I saw them in captured packets but they completed with something like STATUS_NOT_A_REPARSE_POINT. Judging by "reparse point", "symbolic link" definitions and  it seems that client checks that directory or file does not sit at another real place. I don't know if it is required but you may response to these requests as "not a reparse point". However you'd better implement all staff that describes your server data because reparse point is not only a link It could be an encryption key for example.

Comment: This is dumpfile. can you please have a look? Or can you send your dump file so I can compare ?

Comment: It is requesting previous versions for the file New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.XLSX

Comment: @Ashot I can't fully help you I don't SMB2 guru. So suggest you find opensource client that works like a windows client. And go thruogh its' code to see what it needs.

Comment: @Ashot as I can see in your dump. The responses to warp-create have timestamps (last access, write, change) that bigger than snapshot timestamp. Such request must open file that was at that snapshot. But you send response as you open a new file. So system thinks you return the same version of new file.

Comment: @Ashot: also you send the same timestamp information in the reply to SMB2 QUERY_INFO/SMB2_0_INFO_FILE/FileNetworkOpenInformation ([MS-FSCC] 2.4.27, FileNetworkOpenInformation) about file from different snapshots. PS. Not all warp-Create requests should return a file handle.

Answer (score 1):

This may be either a particular windows shape behavior or a bug in your server. We tested with our NQ Storage server and it worked well for both files and folders when the client was 2012. We tested with serveral other windows but I cannot currently recall which ones. Honestly, we did not test snapshots with too many Win shapes. 
If you take a capture, it can give you a hint which side (C or S) is guilty.

Comment: Are you supporting REPARSE_POINTS, Is it required to support previous versions ?

Comment: If I send you the capture file can you tell what part is wrong ?

Comment: At least I will try. you can find me on s k y p e as markrabinovich